# SimpleHttpServer and the Titanium.Web.Proxy

Tags: c#, tcplistener, titanium-web-proxy

I have a C# Windows Forms application that uses the [SimpleHttpServer](https://github.com/jeske/SimpleHttpServer/) class, a "Simple Embeddable HTTP server class in C#", and the titanium-web-proxy, a "cross-platform asynchronous HTTP(S) proxy server in C#". The [SimpleHttpServer](https://github.com/jeske/SimpleHttpServer/) class uses the [System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener) internally.

The application uses the [Titanium.Web.Proxy.ProxyServer.SetAsSystemProxy](https://justcoding121.github.io/titanium-web-proxy/docs/api/Titanium.Web.Proxy.ProxyServer.html#Titanium_Web_Proxy_ProxyServer_SetAsSystemProxy_Titanium_Web_Proxy_Models_ExplicitProxyEndPoint_Titanium_Web_Proxy_Models_ProxyProtocolType_) method to establish a default proxy server for current machine.

The problem is that it appears that the [SimpleHttpServer](https://github.com/jeske/SimpleHttpServer/) is bypassing this proxy server. Is there a way to resolve this issue?